# JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type when I upgrade Json-path to 2.8

Tags: java, jayway

I have a project, which is using jayway jsonpath

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It works well.

I tried to update it to the latest version 2.8.

Then I got some weird compiling errors:
`JSONParser cannot be resolved to a type`
`JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type`
in one Java file. While it has no problem with exact the same code in another Java file which is in test scope.

I tried it in command line and got the same issue. So, it is not IDE issue.
I also checked the version conflict in maven dependency and found no conflict.
This is related code:

```
import net.minidev.json.JSONObject;
import net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser;
import net.minidev.json.parser.ParseException;


    public static JSONObject convertJSONStr2Obj(String jsonStr) throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException, ParseException {
        JSONObject expectedJson = (JSONObject)new JSONParser(JSONParser.DEFAULT_PERMISSIVE_MODE).parse(jsonStr);
        return expectedJson;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out the root cause of this issue:

jayway jsonpath has a dependency on json-smart.

In previous version, it is on `compile` scope, but the latest version the scope is changed to `runtime`, which means package itself doesn't include this library and compiling fails.

But for unit test code, it has no package concept, so it can pass compiling.